# javascript button always disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

This has probably been answered before, and I'd like to apologize for reposting, but since I'm not sure where to start fixing it, I'm not sure what to try and look up for a solution. So bear with me please.

I've got a form for a CMS where I've used a tutorial to dynamically add fields where I need them. EX: The form loads with 0 field entries for bullet points, but if they want some, they can click a button that says add bullet, and voila, a entry field appears. It's in an array. Submits to the DB just fine. The delete button is disabled if there's no fields displayed. All that works fine. If you start out with no fields, on a fresh form. The problem falls into the edit version of this form.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="bullets">
<?php
$sql_bullet_display = 'SELECT * FROM exampleDB.prod_feature_bullets WHERE product_name ="'.$row_product_details['product_name'].'";';
$res_bullet_display = mysql_query($sql_bullet_display) or die(mysql_error().'<br />bad query<br />'. $sql_bullet_display);
$newNum = 1;
while($row_bullet_display = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_bullet_display)){
?>
<div id="bullet<?php echo $newNum; ?>" class="clonedInput2">
<input type="hidden" id="bullet_order<?php echo $newNum; ?>" name="bullet[<?php echo $newNum; ?>][bullet_order]" value="<?php echo $newNum; ?>" />
<input type="text" id="bullet_text<?php echo $newNum; ?>" name="bullet[<?php echo $newNum; ?>][bullet_text]" value='<?php echo $row_bullet_display['bullet_text']; ?>' />
<input type="text" id="bullet_subtext<?php echo $newNum; ?>" name="bullet[<?php echo $newNum; ?>][bullet_subtext]" value='<?php echo $row_bullet_display['sub_text']; ?>' />
</div>
<?php
$newNum++;
}
?>
</div>
<div>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Bullet" />
<input type="button" id="btnDel" value="Remove Bullet" />
</div>
```

and this is the Javascript that goes with it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        var num     = $('.clonedInput2').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

        $('<div id="bullet' + newNum + '" class="clonedInput2"><input type="hidden" id="bullet_order' + newNum + '" name="bullet[' + newNum + '][bullet_order]" value="' + newNum + '" /><input type="text" id="bullet_text' + newNum + '" name="bullet[' + newNum + '][bullet_text]" /><input type="text" id="bullet_subtext' + newNum + '" name="bullet[' + newNum + '][bullet_subtext]" /></div>').appendTo('#bullets'); 

        // enable the "remove" button
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled',''); 

        // business rule: you can only add 15 bullets
        if (newNum == 15)
            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function() {
        var num = $('.clonedInput2').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        $('#bullet' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

        // enable the "add" button
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

        // if no element remains, disable the "remove" button
        if (num == 0)
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

This has worked really well for me in the past, but like I said, it only works on a fresh form that's starting out at 0 bullet entry fields. My problem lies in creating the edit form. I've already got two bullets in the DB that are displayed when you hit edit. The add button shows enabled. The delete button is always disabled when the form first comes up. Even if there's two entries displayed and everything is filled correctly.

However if I click the add button, so a third entry field will show up, it will enable the delete button. Very frustrating. I'm not sure what to go about editing so it'll say: okay, on the page load, we recognize that the DB already filled out two bullets, so the delete button should be active from the start. Every change I've tried so far just breaks the button.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: what is `$('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');` ???? disabled is a marker attribute. if it's there it would be disabled - no matter the value. use `prop`---- `$(...).prop('disabled',true)`

Comment: made the change of anything attr('disabled','') to be prop('disabled',false) and anything attr('disabled','disabled') to be prop('disabled',true). this now makes the delete button appear active with bullets displayed. but now if i hit the delete button until I have no more fields for it, it doesn't disable. trading one issue for another?

Comment: Then man when you delete any field on the delete function you have to go and check if there are any remaining fields. If you still have field even after you delete the one you pressed delete you leave the button active else you disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript code, you have initiliazed the deletebutton to be disabled. you need to check the number of bullets you have created from db...

Modify your last code from:

```
$('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

to

```
if($('.clonedInput2').length<=0){
   $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to remove the disabled attribute

```
$("#btnDel").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: Why not `.prop('disabled',false)` which is the preferred method

Comment: Instead of the $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');? or am I supposed to put that somewhere else? It did't work on the replace. Also didn't work if I place it right inside the document.ready to have it start out enabled.

Comment: @roasted: Well this is the way I used to do it mate. I have to admit that I myself didn't know about this prop method till now.

Comment: @sjvargason `$("#btnDel").removeAttr("disabled");` is equivalent to `$('#btnDel').prop('disabled',false)` just less clean as specified by the DOC

Comment: @Harry At least .removeAttr("disabled"); will work unlike what OP was using: `.attr('disabled','')`

Comment: @sjvargason The way I have done so far is to use `$("#btnDel").attr("disabled" , "disabled");` to disable a button and `$("#btnDel").removeAttr("disabled");` to re-enable it. But I myself just found out about the `.prop(..)` method.

Comment: @roasted - the .prop('disabled',false) method might be more correct, but it's not working. and the .attr('disabled','') is working. the other answer here solves it for now, gonna have to go with that. i'll do some research on the .prop and see if I can figure it out as well. thanks for your input!

Comment: @sjvargason which jquery version are you using?